# Chrome bug: margin-bottom to the browser edge?

Tags: google-chrome, margin

I'm not sure if this is a bug in Google Chrome or if this is wanted, but it really annoys me: If I got something like

```html
<body><div style="margin-bottom: 50px;">much content</div></body>
```

there is no margin shown by Chrome. The `div` just ends at the bottom browser edge. Literally, any other browser renders this correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a padding-bottom to the element containing your div, even if it's the body element.
This works in all browsers, so you will have to remove the bottom margin from the div.

Comment: Is your Chrome up to date? It's now at version 11 (check on it's about box)

Comment: okay, forget it. it was obviously my fault :O just used height: 100% in all my common stylesheets so it came to this mistake on all my projects, lol.

Comment: Anyone who downvotes a two years old accepted answer should be a little kind and leave a comment why that downvote was necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your whole site (or just the area that has the margin you want to capture) in a

```
<div style="overflow:auto;"></div>
```

If setting padding does not appeal to you, try the above. I didn't want to set padding, because a margin on the bottom of boxes is my standard way of making room for the next box when data is dynamic and I don't know whether there will be one.

Margins will not "bleed through" a box with overflow specified, so this fixes the problem in Chrome by allowing that last box to have margin inside the new overflow:auto div.

This change is inconsequential to the other browsers who were blocking that margin bleed anyway. I tested in IE 8 and up for regressions on that side and found none.

Answer (score 2):

On Google Chrome `{padding-bottom: XXpx;}` doesn't work, but `{padding-bottom: XXem;}` does.

Note the first uses pixels and second ems.

Answer (score 0):

The css padding and margin directives work fine in IE, but not in Chrome. Chrome just ignores them, if they are placed in a .css file. To resolve this problem, put all the padding and margin instructions in a separate file within the <STYLE> tags, and then include it with the help of <?php include ('margins.php');?>. or <!--#include virtual="margins.php"--> into all of your pages, because these directives works in Chrome perfectly if they contained on the page.